# How to give a custom CSS style for the "disabled" state when customizing a webkit scrollbar button

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

Normal chrome scrollbar arrow buttons have a disabled-like state when the scrollbar thumb is all the way to the arrow.

There are `::-webkit-scrollbar*` selectors for styling scrollbars.

What selector can I use to style that particular state of the button? `::webkit-scrollbar-button:disabled` does not work for this state.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/mattyork/pen/oGWOZY?editors=1100

[image]

Comment: The disabled-like state of the scrollbar exist only for Chrome, so it's probably a browser-side thing. I don't think this is possible in html/css

Comment: @toto1911, you are correct, but the customize styles can have a better view only in mac, not in windows.

Comment: There are no `::webkit-scrollbar*` selectors for styling a disabled-like state. Basically, it is not possible to customize scrollbar using `::-webkit-scrollbar*` to mimick the way chrome disables the scrollbar button when the scrollbar thumb is all the way to the arrow.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer**

From my basic research, I'm not sure this is possible. Based on this [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) page, which I'd bet you've seen, it doesn't list any pseudo selectors for active or inactive scrollbar buttons. Here are the listed selectors.

```
:horizontal
:vertical
:decrement
:increment
:start
:end 
:double-button
:single-button
:no-button
:corner-present
:window-inactive
```

Instead, you might consider removing the buttons all together.

Answer (score 2):

If there is nothing to scroll to, I would just hide the scrollbar altogether.

```
body {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100vh;
     }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. He doesn't want to disable scrolling which this would do. He simply wants to style a "disabled" scrollbar button when it is full scrolled to one end or the other.

Comment: I answered it from a usability POV rather than an implementation POV.

Comment: ah, fair enough. Your answer makes sense, but I thought he wanted to style the top button when the scroll bar is at the top, and the bottom button when the bar is at the bottom.

Comment: I believe several usability guidelines state not to fiddle with the default settings on the page, including scrollbars: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/scrolling-and-scrollbars/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this by using jquery plugin.

Here I have attached the [Github link.](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin)

Here is the [Plugin webpage.](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

You can also find the examples for the scrollbar from this [link](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html).

---

Another Method:

**CSS Scrollbar Customisation**

```css
    * {
      list-style:none;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    body {
      background: #333;
      padding:20px;
    }
    #content {
      background:transparent;
      height:400px;
      padding:0 10px 0 0;
      width:400px;
    }
    #content li {
      background:#666;
      height:100px;
      margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    #content li:last-child { margin-bottom: 0; }

    .scrollable-content {
      overflow-x:hidden;
      overflow-y:scroll;
    }
    .scrollable-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width:30px;
    }
    .scrollable-content::-webkit-scrollbar * {
      background:transparent;
    }
    .scrollable-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background:#999 !important;
    }
```

```html
<ol class="scrollable-content" id="content">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Hope this may helps you.

Comment: this is great and does achieve what was asked for - but I think it must be the default behaviour of the scrollbar?

Comment: Yes this is a default behavior of the browser, the pure CSS option may fail to work in windows, but the plugin which I have mentioned having full cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: yes I looked at the plugin - most of the scrollbars looked difficult to use because of their weird styling.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of doing this via JavaScript,

```
// Every time the window scrolls.
addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    // When scrollbar is at its zenith, do your CSS.
    if (!document.querySelector("style[data-id=myStyle"))
        head.innerHTML += `<style data-id=myStyle> ::-webkit-scrollbar { opacity: .5 } </style>`;

    // When scrollbar is not at the top, remove the CSS.
    else
        (document.querySelector("style[data-id=myStyle") || document.createElement("style")).remove()
}, false)
```

I'm sure if this is really possible in CSS, but I really want to be wrong on that. For now, this is all I've got.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using :disabled before ::-webkit-scrollbar, like in this example:

```
:disabled ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
    background-position-y: -34px !important;
}

:disabled ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
    background-position-y: -34px !important;
}


:disabled ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:decrement {
    background-position-y: -34px !important;
}

:disabled ::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:horizontal:increment {
    background-position-y: -34px !important;
}
```

It worked for my case, the background-position-y correspond to the position of the image where the disabled state is.